# C# Npgsql, Call of procedure supported ?

Tags: c#, npgsql

with regards to the new update of postgresSQL (ver 11). Procedures are now supported. Procedures can be created using the CREATE PROCEDURE command and executed using the CALL command.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyInsert(_sno text, _eid text, _sd date)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO app_for_leave(sno, eid, sd)
    VALUES(_sno, _eid, _sd);   
$$;

CALL MyInsert('4','5','2013-04-04');
```

Is the "CALL" supported right now ?

Currently i can only make it work by building a String as a command and then executing it.
e.g.

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
         conn.Open();
          using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
          {
               cmd.CommandText = "CALL MyInsert('4','5','2013-04-04')";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
         conn.Close();
}
```

Please do let me know if there is a better way of executing the "MyInsert" without building the query string. This is susceptible to sql injection as it is not a prepared statement.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Github issue duplicate: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a regular command with CALL proc_name() is perfectly fine for executing stored procedures - there's nothing else that's needed really. Nothing about this is more or less susceptible to SQL injection: you can still pass parameters as usual by specifying parameter placeholders (e.g. @param1, @param2). Note that parameters and placeholders also have nothing to do with prepared statements - it's perfectly valid to send parameters (and therefore be protected against SQL injection) with a non-prepared statements

The PostgreSQL protocol doesn't have any special provisions for calling functions or procedures. Even when you use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` for calling functions, all this does is make Npgsql construct a `SELECT func_name()` under the hood and send it as a normal command.